# SQL Server 2012 32 bit - will enabling locked pages allow it to use more memory?

Tags: sql-server-2012, memory, installation

I recently found out, that a server got a 32 bit installation of SQL Server 2012 rather than 64bit, and it is running out of memory now.

Can I have this 32 bit installation use more memory using locked pages?

I do not know much about this. I've read this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2659143/en-us bit I am still not clear if this will help, what needs to be done etc

Comment: How long are you going to fight this thing, instead of doing the right thing and installing a proper, 64-bit instance?

Comment: 32 bit still exists in serverland?

Comment: we had trouble getting a 64 bit version on time, but we made it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Can I have this 32 bit installation use more memory using locked pages?*

In the past, my answer would have been (a heavily qualified) "yes".

Using `AWE` (address windowing extensions) would enable up to 64GB memory. Unfortunately (from your point of view, perhaps) 32-bit `AWE` was [removed from the database engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/discontinued-database-engine-functionality-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) starting with SQL Server 2012.

In previous versions, 32-bit SQL Server running on a 64-bit version of Windows (WOW mode) was a [supported configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/slavao/q-and-a-enabling-awe-settings-for-sql-server-32-bit-edition-in-wow) but one that I never encountered personally. Anecdotally, such configurations were often problematic; if you enjoy tracking down weird problems, 32-bit `AWE` SQL Server on 64-bit Windows is for you.

My very strong recommendation would be to use 64-bit SQL Server 2012 instead.